# Karaf Cellar and Managed Service

Tags: karaf

I've a cluster of two nodes with Cellar. There are managed service set on a configuration create with the configuration admin service.

When I update configuration, there is only one managed service which triggered instead of two.
But when I stop the first node, the managed service is triggered on the other node receiving updated configuration.

I expect  that the managed service triggered on two nodes at the same time.

Thanks

Configuration

Karaf 3.0.7
Karaf Cellar 3.0.3

```
Event producer=true
Event consumer=true

bundle.listener = false
config.listener = true
feature.listener = false

default.bundle.sync = cluster
default.config.sync = cluster
default.feature.sync = cluster
default.obr.urls.sync = cluster
```

Comment: Can you please be a bit more clear on what is that you are trouble with?

Comment: My managed service is plugged on a configuration. When I update this configuration the data are correctly synchronized between the two nodes. But my managed service is only triggered on one node.